# QGIS parts to single part with a given minimal distance of the parts

Tags: qgis

Is it possible to split lines into parts and give a minimal distance for the parts to be split?

I have a layer with rivers, some of them are one object, even if they are hundreds of kilometers away from each other. How can I split them into dedicated lines?

If I use the tool parts-to-single, the lines will be split into small segments. I want to say: split if the parts are >50km away from other parts, to get single, but complete lines for each river.

Answer (score 2):

*Starting data* :

- `rivers` layer with a unique identifier `river_id` to identify each objects, each grouped segments of rivers

*Processing* :

1. Do a **buffer** on `rivers`, not dissolved, with a distance of `50 km / 2` so `25 km`. If you want strictly `>`, you can do a buffer of `24.9999` km
2. Your `buffer_25km` has a `river_id`, so **dissolve** this layer and select as `Dissolve field` `river_id`.
3. Apply on the new `buffer_25km_dissolved` a **Multipart to Singleparts**
4. Create an unique field on the `single_buffer_25km_dissolved` to identify each patch `buffer_id` updated with `$id`
5. Apply on `rivers` a **Multipart to Singleparts**
6. Create a new field (integer) on `single_rivers` and retrieve the `buffer_id` data into this field by location or `overlap_within(` expression
7. Dissolve `single_rivers` and select as `Dissolve field` `river_id` and `buffer_id`